# How to add wordpress template to a custom php search page

Tags: wordpress

I made a custom php search page called search.php. I link to it from a form in my wordpress website, but the search page is just white with no template. How can I get the wordpress template/look to surround the search results of the search.php page?

Comment: No. what happened is i created a search.php outside of wordpress. Then uploaded it to the server where the wordpress website is. Do I just need to figure out what include files from the wordpress site to include at the beginning of my new php page?

Answer (score 0):

All the search queries are handled by search.php, get a fresh copy of search.php and then make changes to it.